# Spark and Spring boot integration

Tags: java, apache-spark, spring-boot

We are trying to integrate Spark and Spring boot, unfortunately we are facing each time lot of issues. After resolving the most of them, we are now stuck on the exception below

```
Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 11.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 11.0 (TID 14, xxxxx.ax.internal.cloudapp.net, executor 1): java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy to field org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$dependencies_ of type scala.collection.Seq in instance of org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2233)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1405)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2284)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2202)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2060)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1567)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2278)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2202)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2060)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1567)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:427)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:80)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1435)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1423)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1650)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1605)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1594)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:628)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1928)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1941)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1954)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:336)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2386)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$withNewExecutionId(Dataset.scala:2788)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1(Dataset.scala:2385)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collect(Dataset.scala:2392)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2128)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2127)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withTypedCallback(Dataset.scala:2818)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2127)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2342)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:248)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:638)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:597)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:606)
        at com.xxx.xxx.spark.Execute.run(Execute.java:46)
        at com.xxx.xxx.spark.Loader.process(Loader.java:505)
        at com.xxx.xxx.spark.Loader.run(Loader.java:122)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:732)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:716)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:703)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:304)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
        at com.xxx.xxx.spark.AnalyseFec.main(AnalyseFec.java:11)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

This exception is raised when trying to manipulate a transformed data set (created with a map). The count and collect methods works fine,

The sample below throw the exception on dataf22.show();

```
StructType schemata = DataTypes.createStructType(
                new StructField[]{
                        DataTypes.createStructField("Column1", DataTypes.StringType, false),
                        DataTypes.createStructField("Column2", DataTypes.DoubleType, false),
                        DataTypes.createStructField("Column3", DataTypes.DoubleType, false),
                });

        ExpressionEncoder<Row> encoder = RowEncoder.apply(schemata);

        Dataset<Row> dataf2 = session.read()
                .option("header", "true")
                .option("delimiter",separateur)
//              .schema(schemata)
                .csv(csvPath);


        dataf2.write().mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).parquet("xxx.parquet");
        Dataset<Row> parquetFileDF = session.read().parquet("xxx.parquet");

        Dataset<Row> dataf22 = parquetFileDF.map(row -> {
            return RowFactory.create(row.getAs("Column1"), 
                    Double.parseDouble(row.getAs("Column2").toString().replace(",", ".")),
                    Double.parseDouble(row.getAs("Column3").toString().replace(",", ".")));
        }, encoder);

        dataf22.printSchema();
        dataf22.show();

        dataf22.groupBy("Column1");
        Dataset<Row> ds1 = dataf22.groupBy("Column1").sum("Column2");
        ds1.show();
        Dataset<Row> ds2 = dataf22.groupBy("Column1").sum("Column3");
        ds2.show();
```

Initially we were packaging using the spring-boot-maven-plugin, the spark-submit was calling the org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher that launch our starter class.

When we moved to maven-shade-plugin with some modification to support spring boot, the exception above disappear and we were able to execute our program, but only in client mode. In cluster mode the application is never running in Yarn, after multiple attempt the application Fail without any error that can help to fix the issue.

I feel that once the program is executed on executors, the problem will appear related to classpath or classloader issues

Did you succeed to made this integration working ? If yes, what maven plugin did you used ? what extra parameters of spark-submit command did you uses ( extraclasspath … )

Thank you

Comment: I don't think this error has anything to do with Maven (it's a runtime error, not a build error). It also reads like you're casting between wrong datatypes, not missing any classpath problems. Please edit your question to include the full stacktrace and a [mcve]

Comment: At least, if it were a classpath problem, you need to check which version(s) of Spark that Spring supports, then check all your versions align accordingly (plus using the provided scope of Maven if using a uber jar)

Comment: I added more details. Of course it's a runtime issue but it may be related to a packaging issue. For instance, there is an issue with logback and slf4j between spark & spring boot, exclusion must be added in order to avoid this. Spark depdencies are marked as provided.

Also, the same code is working fine in client mode ...

Comment: I'm somewhat surprised your first dataset was fine. However, is there a specific reason you need to dump a Dataset, then read it back from disk rather than just manipulating the one you already have?

Comment: I did it to test with million of lines and see if it's more intersting to use the parquet then the classic format. For the moment, i'm not able to go further. Any case, it's not related to the issue we have

Comment: My point is that `parquetFileDF.map` is causing some issue, and should be no different than trying `dataf2.map`. I might also recommend trying to map to an actual class rather than a collection of Rows.

Comment: Thank you for your reply
I removed the parquet and simplfy more the map
Dataset<Row> dataf2 = session.read()
    .option("header", "true")
    .option("delimiter",sep)
    .csv(csvPath);
Dataset<String> dataf22 = dataf2.map(row -> {
   return row.getAs("Column1").toString();
  }, Encoders.STRING());
  
dataf22.printSchema();
dataf22.show();

Still have the same issue on the same line